# How to round a list of decimals in Excel, so that the sum of the whole numbers equal a defined total?

Tags: excel, vba, rounding

Having difficulty developing an excel function that will round a list of decimals, so that the sum of the whole numbers equals the original or a defined total.

**Edit**
I guess one way to do it is writing a function that first searches for the largest numbers and rounds them to the nearest whole number.  That whole number is then counted and the function moves on to the next, until the total count equals the target total.

The problem that I am running into is that if there are too many numbers that are closer to 0, then the function will never equal the target total. So what the function then needs to do is identify the largest decimals, round them up, count, and then move on to the next until the sum of the count is equal to the target total. The left over data can then round to 0.

Sorry, I hope this is clearer....

I am dealing with larger data sets where the totals of the rounded whole numbers have much larger deviations to the original total.

It would preferable if this could be accomplished with an excel function, otherwise I am also open to doing in VBA.

Thanks!

Edit 3: Here is an example data set:

[image]

Comment: Are you saying you're free to either round up or down to the nearest whole number, regardless of the value of the decimal part?

Comment: Seems like the arithmetic of rounding could always cause a deviation.  What I usually do is plug the difference into the last row.  Otherwise, wouldn't you need an algorithm to allocate the difference in some way?  I wonder if this is more of an arithmetic problem than an Excel function problem.

Comment: Round all the numbers down and sum them - take the difference between the sum and the goal ("x") and round the first x numbers up (assuming the goal is reachable given the inputs)

Comment: Thanks for the help...I realized that my original description was off, so I edited it.  Please review and let me know if you have any ideas.

Comment: It's not clear why a simpler approach wouldn't work - it would be useful if you could explain exactly what the "fitness" calculation would be for any given approach.  Why choose one over another - what are you optimizing for?

Comment: @TimWilliams: While a method is simple to figure out, an implementation takes a lot more. See my answer, please.

Comment: @TimWilliams some background: I have a list of hundreds of stores that are supposed to get a % share of a specific product (% Share based on historical sales). With the volume defined, I need a function that will take the defined volume and distribute them across all stores based on the % share.  The returned whole numbers should not exceed the original defined volume.  One problem that I run into is that I sometimes deal with such small volumes that are distributed across a many stores and the rounded values are zeroed out.

Comment: It's not clear why the approaches suggested won't work?  Or they do and you're just adding some context?

Comment: @TimWilliams - I don't see the approach you suggest working, because there are scenarios where distribution values are so small, they will all round to 0. So in that scenario the function should select the largest decimals and assign an integer to them, until the sum of the integers equal the defined volume.

Comment: In your question you state "The left over data can then round to 0" so I assumed that wasn't a problem?  Basically you've still not described what your *constraints* are: what outcomes are *not acceptable*, or what are you trying to optimize for ?  Without that it's easy to suggested solutions.

Comment: @TimWilliams sorry for not being clear... I have difficulty explaining this.  I updated the above with an example data set.  I am just trying to figure out how to distribute a fair share of volume to stores that perform the best.

Comment: How is `distribution` calculated from `% distribution`?

Comment: @JMP - I updated the screenshot above with an explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please study my project [VBA.Round](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.Round).

Browse to paragraph [Rounding a series of numbers to a sum](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.Round#rounding-a-series-of-numbers-to-a-sum)

Code is way too much to post here, but an example workbook is included for download.

**Example**:

This function will read the range of distribution values, round the sum, and fill the two ranges with rounded values of 2 and zero decimals, totalling to the requested total (confirmed, as seen, by the formula):

```vb
' Practical example for using Excel ranges for RoundSum
'
' Source URL:
'   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63715043/how-to-round-a-list-of-decimals-in-excel-so-that-the-sum-of-the-whole-numbers-e
'
' 2020-09-14. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Sub RoundDistribution()

    ' Named ranges. These should pairwise match in row size.
    Const VolumeName        As String = "Volume"
    Const PercentValuesName As String = "Percent_Distribution"
    Const ValuesName        As String = "Distribution"
    Const RoundedValuesName As String = "Rounded_Distribution"
    
    Dim Range       As Excel.Range
    
    Dim Values()    As Currency
    Dim Results()   As Currency
    
    Dim Total       As Integer
    Dim Index       As Integer
    
    ' Read percent distribution values from the named range.
    Set Range = ThisWorkbook.Names(PercentValuesName).RefersToRange
    ' Read original volume value.
    Total = ThisWorkbook.Names(VolumeName).RefersToRange(1, 1)
    
    ' Dim input and output arrays.
    ReDim Values(1 To Range.Rows.Count)
    ReDim Results(1 To Range.Rows.Count)
    
    ' Fill input array.
    For Index = LBound(Values) To UBound(Values)
        Values(Index) = Range(Index, 1)
    Next
    
    ' Round total and retrieve array with distribution values.
    Results = RoundSum(Values, RoundMid(Total), 2)
    
    ' Fill named range with distribution values.
    For Index = LBound(Results) To UBound(Results)
        ThisWorkbook.Names(ValuesName).RefersToRange(Index, 1) = Results(Index)
    Next
    
    ' Round total and retrieve array with rounded distribution values.
    Results = RoundSum(Values, RoundMid(Total))
    
    ' Fill named range with rounded distribution values.
    For Index = LBound(Results) To UBound(Results)
        ThisWorkbook.Names(RoundedValuesName).RefersToRange(Index, 1) = Results(Index)
    Next
    
End Sub
```

Output:

[image]

Note please, that the function is capable of rounding to any number of decimals, and to select *one instance only* of the values 0.34 to obtain a match.

*The full demo (Excel workbook) and code is still for download on* **GitHub**.

Comment: Someone - in error, I assume - downvoted my answer.  Please revert that.

Comment: Gustav thanks for the help! Note that the decimal values are generated when the total volume is inputted in cell C31 and then distributed across the percentages  in column B.  I downloaded your workbook and played around the with the macro and it does seem to accomplish my goal.  I will try this out with other applications and provide you feedback.  Thanks again!

Comment: Oh, missed the source of the Distribution total. Then, I guess, the values from the `% Distribution` column should be used.

Comment: When I enter the `% Distribution` values as shown, they sum to `100.03%`. So, are these rounded to two decimals? What would the unrounded values be?

Comment: Sorry that was not clear it would have been easier to upload the workbook, but I am currently unable to.  I updated the screen shot without any rounded figures in excel, with a better detailed explanation of the columns.

Comment: It is just a question of rounding to two decimals to get also the Distribution column right. See updated demo, please.

Comment: This method worked really well when applying it to actual data sets that I was working with.  I only ran into problems when running the macro in other workbooks after redefining the constants. I get a "Sub or Function not defined" error.  I think it will just take some tweaking to automate, but I think this a great foundation.  Thanks so much for your help!  I am definitely buying you some coffee!

Comment: Great! It should be easy to copy the code module to the real workbook. Of course, names of the _Named Ranges_ must be modified, but I can highly recommend to stick with Named Ranges rather than, perhaps, falling back to simple cell references.

Answer (score 0):

I'd agree with @pghcpa this is rather an arithmetic problem.
One idea for solution:

1. order the numbers descending on their fraction part
2. take the floor of each (i.e ignoring the fractions)
3. take the sum of those floors
4. compare that sum to the desired sum, take the difference
   This way you'd *probably* have a positive difference, so you can start from the top and add 1 to each number downwards, all until the difference is gone.